# table not displaying correctly in outlook

Tags: outlook, html-email, newsletter

I have an email that contains the following table. When tested in gmail looks absolutely fine but in outlook the width of the table shrinks and the border doesn't show as it should. I have tried everything I could but it doesn't seem to work. If you have any ideas please share.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0; width: 100% !important;">
<thead style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top: 0;">
<tr style="color: #000; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; font-weight: bold; color: #f2a489; margin: 0; font-size: 12px; padding-top: 15px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-top: 0; text-align: left;">Item</th>
<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; font-weight: bold; color: #f2a489; margin: 0; font-size: 12px; padding-top: 15px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: left;">Size</th>
<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; font-weight: bold; color: #f2a489; margin: 0; font-size: 12px; padding-top: 15px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; text-align: right;">Quantity</th>
<th style="border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc; font-weight: bold; color: #f2a489; margin: 0; font-size: 12px; padding-top: 15px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 0; text-align: right;">Subtotal</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin-bottom: 0;">
<tr style="color: #000; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-top: 0;">
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; margin-top: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: left;">Cadburys overload</td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: left;">Minis</td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: right;">6</td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: right;">£ 33.00</td>
</tr>
<tr style="color: #000; margin: 0; padding: 0;">
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; margin-top: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: left;">Fruit Overload</td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: left;">Large</td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: right;">1</td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: right;">£ 78.00</td>
</tr>
<tr style="color: #000; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 0;">
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; margin-top: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: left;">Total paid</td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: left;"></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: right;"></td>
<td style="font-size: 12px; font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; margin: 0; margin-bottom: 0; border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc !important; padding: 10px 0 !important; text-align: right;">£ 111.00</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Please see the images attached with the table in gmail(how it should look) and in outlook
[image] 
[image]

I have attached the code here https://jsfiddle.net/ry2sfq61/

Thanks!

Comment: Outlook has buggy support for adding a border to a table cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `!important` from the width on the `table` element, so the width is just: `width: 100%;`.

If that doesn't work you may need to fix a static width, not percentage ie `width: 600px`.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook is notoriously buggy when it comes to applying a border to a `<td>`.

Add this to the `td` inline style sheets where you want a border:

`mso-border-bottom-alt: solid #cccccc 1pt;`

If you want a table that is a specific width, you have to add:

`<table width="600">` You can try `<table style="width: 600px;">`

Sometimes Outlook will ignore `width: 100%;` or `width: 600px;` and other properties in the inline style sheet. It can be a real headache.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, you could change `<table>` to the below code:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, sans-serif; border-collapse: collapse; padding: 0;">
```

This is my result:

[image]